# Apache Superset Connection to Mariadb via Spark

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark, mariadb, apache-superset

I would like to view data from Mariadb in Superset. I think getting the data from Mariadb --> Spark --> Superset might be the best solution because I will also use Spark with H2o Sparkling Water.

**1.** I have tried **pip3 install mysqlclient** but got this error:

```
ERROR: Command "/bin/python3 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize; ... failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-kslmastj/mysqlclient/
```

**2.** I tried Spark with 2 configuration files but I do not think the data is accessible in Spark or Spark SQL.

**File 1** ../conf/spark-defaults.conf

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath = /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath = /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar
```

**File 2** ../conf/hive-site.xml

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
      <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBNAME</value>
      <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
      <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
      <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
   </property>
     <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
      <value>USERNAME</value>
      <description>username to use against metastore database</description>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
      <value>PASSWORD</value>
      <description>password to use against metastore database</description>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

**3.** I read about the [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/index.html) dialects and [PyHive](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/config/). I searched through the superset code and cannot determine where to add the external dialects.

**4.** I have tried a few configurations in the superset config file.  I am wondering if the port should be the Spark port.
**SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'hive://localhost:4040/'**

**5.** I attempted to import a csv file but got an error.

**NOTE:** I can see the Mariadb data in Spark if I enter this at the scala prompt but I don't think this is the proper solution.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
val sqlcontext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val dataframe_mysql = sqlcontext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DATABASE_NAME").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "TABLE_NAME").option("user", "USER_NAME").option("password", "PASSWORD").load()
dataframe_mysql.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

I have connected a MariaDB with superset as my main BD instead the default SQLite, probably this will help you to connect.

SQLAlchemist needs an extra python lib for this task, in my case I have used pymysql.
Once installed (you can use pip) the connection will be with the prefix **mysql+pymysql**, so it will have this look:

```
'mysql+pymysql://user:password@host/dbname'
```

Comment: Thanks,  I was able to get it connected to MariaDB with this line in the config file. `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://USER:PASSWORD@localhost:3306/SCHEMA'`

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating OP's partial solution from question to an answer:</sub>

> It is not the ideal solution but I was able to get **pip3 install mysqlclient** to work after reading the solution at this [link](https://centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=65567).
>
> ```
> sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libmariadbclient.a /usr/lib64/libmariadb.a
> ```